# How can a badge like on GitHub libraries be made?

Tags: java, android, badge

How can I make a badge like how we ofter see it on GitHub libraries. Like this: [image]. I can use a web view but it is not efficient as it will take time to load and it will also cache it.

Comment: i don't necessarily have any problems with your post, others might disagree, but this seems like an extremely niche requirement, can't say i've ever needed something like this and i probably wouldn't recommend on making use of third party libraries just to achieve something like this

Comment: Self-answered questions are encouraged and self-promotion is not automatically bad, but please make sure that both the question and the answer meet the normal quality bar. Specifically your answer looks like a direct copy of (parts of) your projects readme, which is not a proper answer. Consider editing it down to a useful answer. Also, make sure that the formatting looks like you intended it. Right now it's a mess (with extra `<hr>`, broken images/videos and broken lists)

Comment: the the links have been corrected

Comment: @JoachimSauer I have edited my answer. Please let me know if it is ok 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, I have made a library [Badge Generator](https://github.com/sambhav2358/BadgeGenerator). It is easy to implement. The steps are given below. I will be editing the answer as I post updates.

### Sample

[This is the sample video](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/97180951/156737133-298fd35c-9092-417c-9917-9e9a3f563ecf.mp4)

### Tutorial

[This is the youtube tutorial](https://youtu.be/AdBj-rSsBog)

**Note:** This is not updated to the features supported in the latest version.

### Features

1. You can set a custom label(title)
2. You can set a custom message
3. You can set a custom image using `base64` or the two links provided in the `README.md`.
4. You can set a custom logo color
5. You can set a custom label background color
6. You can set a custom message background color
7. And a lot lot more.

### Downsides

---

1. The quality decreases with images but remains good without them